# MIMIC III - C-Reactive protein

Tags: mimic-iii

I'm trying to find CRP values in the MIMIC-III database.
I've tried different search strategies but I've only found two items (227444, 220612) in the d_items table, which are both empty variables.
Are there any CRP data available in the database? If yes, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lab results are shared between the tables *labevents* and *chartevents*: [see here](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/7039/why-are-lab-tests-splitted-into-2-tables-chartevents-and-labevents).

The itemids found in the table d_items refer mainly to the table *chartevents*. I have found 743 results in *chartevents* using the itemid **227444**. 220612 does not seem to be used anywhere.

In the table *d_labitems* you will find that the itemid **50889** also corresponds to CRP, but is connected to the table *labevents*. There are 6604 records of CRP in *labevents* using this itemid.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT hadm_id, subject_id, charttime, itemid, valuenum, valueuom
FROM mimiciii.chartevents 
WHERE itemID = 227444
AND valuenum IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY hadm_id, charttime
```

gives 743 records

```
SELECT hadm_id, subject_id, charttime, itemid, valuenum, valueuom
FROM mimiciii.labevents 
WHERE itemid = 50889
AND valuenum IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY hadm_id, charttime
```

gives 6393 records

```
SELECT hadm_id, subject_id, charttime, itemid, valuenum, valueuom
FROM mimiciii.chartevents WHERE itemID = 227444
AND valuenum IS NOT NULL
UNION
SELECT hadm_id, subject_id, charttime, itemid, valuenum, valueuom  
FROM mimiciii.labevents 
WHERE itemid = 50889
AND valuenum IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY hadm_id, charttime
```

gives 7136 records

The chartevents entries are duplicates of the labevents entries.